# Custom yaml syntax

Tags: ruby, yaml, jekyll, liquid

Im using Jekyll and liquid syntax and would like to add a custom background colour and thumbnail image for each of my projects on my homepage. How can I achieve this using YAML frontmatter?

**liquid syntax outputting projects**

```
{% for post in site.categories['project'] %}
    <div class="project">
            <h3 class="project__title">{{ post.title }}</h3>
            <p class="project__description">{{ post.description }}</p>
            <a class="project__link" href="{{ post.url}}">view project</a>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: What does this question have to do with Sass, HTML, or Ruby?

Comment: Liquid is a ruby library, correct? @cimmanon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your project posts add `background` and `thumbnail` variables

**myprojectpage.html**

```
---
front matter variables ...
background: #ffffff
thumbnail: images/myproject.jpg
---
```

You can then use them in your loop :

```
{% for post in site.categories['project'] %}
  <div class="project" style="background:{{post.background}};">
    <h3 class="project__title">{{ post.title }}</h3>
    <img src="{{ site.baseurl }}/{{ post.thumbnail }}" alt="post.title">
    <p class="project__description">{{ post.description }}</p>
    <a class="project__link" href="{{ post.url}}">view project</a>
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Another option can be to simply add a class to your post and manage style in your css/scss/less file.

Comment: How would I overlay the image with the background color? This seems to work but its littering my mark-up - <div class="project" style="background: linear-gradient({{post.background}},{{post.background}}), url({{ post.thumb }});">. I dont really want to have any inline css

Comment: No worries, ive found a solution, but wouldnt have got there without yours. thanks.